# Connecting ArcGIS for Desktop to Oracle without ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, oracle-spatial

Is it possible to connect ArcMap to Oracle without ArcGIS for Server?

Comment: What has your research into this indicated?  My suspicion is that the answer is readily available on the web and maybe on this site too.

Comment: Try searching on "ArcGIS Desktop Query Layers".

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You might want to try Google rather than Stack Exchange for these kinds of questions (in the first instance).  Top hit for Googling "connect arcgis desktop to oracle" was:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-oracle/connect-oracle.htm